# Trying to get numbered lines to right of text

Tags: python, tkinter

I am lost and have tried multiple attempts. I am needing to have a text editor that will allow me to open the file and add numbered lines to the right of the text. This is the current code that I have but when I attempt to add something to count and number the lines of text I get errors.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
def open_file():
    filepath = askopenfilename(
        filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")]
    )
    if not filepath:
        return
    txt_edit.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    with open(filepath, "r") as input_file:
        text = input_file.read()
        txt_edit.insert(tk.END, text)
    window.title(f"Line count and numbered - {filepath}")



def text_lines(file):
    filepath = numberefile(
        filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")]
    )
    if not filepath:
        return
    with open(filepath, "r") as numbered_file:
        numberedlist = numberedfile.readline()
        i = 0
        for lines in numberdlist:
            i = i + 1
            print
            str(i) + '\t' + lines
    numberdfile.close()

def save_file():
    filepath = asksaveasfilename(
        defaultextension="txt",
        filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")],
    )
    if not filepath:
        return
    with open(filepath, "w") as output_file:
        text = txt_edit.get("1.0", tk.END)
        output_file.write(text)
        window.title(f"Line count and numbered - {filepath}")

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Line count and numbered")
window.rowconfigure(0, minsize=800, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(2, minsize=800, weight=1)
txt_edit = tk.Text(window)
fr_buttons = tk.Frame(window, relief=tk.RAISED, bd=2)
btn_open = tk.Button(fr_buttons, text="Open", command=open_file)
btn_save = tk.Button(fr_buttons, text="Save As...", command=save_file)
btn_numbers = tk.Button(fr_buttons, text="Number lines", command=text_lines)
btn_open.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
btn_save.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5)
btn_numbers.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
fr_buttons.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns")
txt_edit.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please explain which errors you get?  Are they formatting errors (i.e. the output doesn't look like it should),in which case show us what it should look like.  If it is a run time error. then paste into your question the entire error message beginning with the word traceback.  If other error, please explain

Comment: Sorry meant to remove or comment to advise I corrected this problem and have it working now.

Comment: If you have a correct solution, let us know about it and provide answer or close question